# Stack items when mobile with Magento 1.9 and RWD theme

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

I just found a lot of posts but none of them show a clear answer that works: how can I display 3 items in a row when user is desktop and stack them vertically when in mobile?

I see this is possible with no hacking for product grid (but products are shown two by row), probably I can use the something similar for the same result.

I have created this sample which is able to show 3 items when desktop and show 2 in a row and 1 in another. That's close to what I want:

```
<ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-4-col first last odd">
<li><img alt="" src="http://192.241.128.153/media/wysiwyg/index/pencil.jpg" />
<div class="product-info" style="min-height: 167px;">
<h2>Assine</h2>
</div>
</li>
<li><img alt="" src="http://192.241.128.153/media/wysiwyg/index/pencil.jpg" />
<div class="product-info" style="min-height: 167px;">
<h2>Vote</h2>
</div>
</li>
<li><img alt="" src="http://192.241.128.153/media/wysiwyg/index/pencil.jpg" />
<div class="product-info" style="min-height: 148px;">
<h2>Receba</h2>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a media query in your CSS such as..

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 770px) {
      .products-grid li {
           width: 100%;
      }
 }
```

Don't forget the product list version too.

Comment: Hello @womblegold, sorry by being so newbie, but could you please post a complete html sample of what you're suggesting? :D

Comment: Hi, this would't go in your HTML, it would sit in your custom CSS stylesheet.